# How to approach mentor about moving from unpaid to paid research position as undergraduate

Tags: undergraduate, research-undergraduate

I am an undergraduate student in my fifth year. I am currently working on a research project with a professor I met while studying abroad. I am no longer abroad, but I plan on continuing my work with this professor. We have already submitted a paper for review, and are starting work on another paper.

This semester, I am looking for a source of income, and I was wondering if I could be taken on as a paid assistant researcher. I would do this research regardless of if I am paid or not, but if the university is able to procure funds to pay me, I would gladly take them . If I were paid, I would be willing to take on a larger workload, and even potentially work on additional projects. Currently, my work is pretty sporadic. Some weeks I might not work on the project at all, while other weeks I can work over 20 hours.

I am wondering if it is rude or inappropriate to approach the mentor about the possibility of being paid. Ideally, the university would take me on as a part-time research assistant, but I'm unsure if that is possible now that I am no longer abroad and of the responsibilities that would entail. How should I go about asking my mentor about this, if I should at all?

If anyone is familiar with the laws governing remote work, I reside in the U.S. and the university is in Spain.

Comment: Paid by a university in another country? Could be difficult because of tax laws and hiring laws.

Comment: @JonCuster yeah, I just don't know what those laws are. I would still like to look into it to see if it is indeed possible

Comment: In my country, you fall out of the student social security if you work more than 40h/month. Suddenly you pay for health insurance, unemployment, pension system, ...

Comment: @Karl in Germany it's 80h/month, but you're allowed to work more during the semester break. I don't know if there is a EU wide regulation that applies for all its members

Comment: @Sursula I remember there was something about "Werkstudenten" where the limit was higher. Never applied to me, and it's a long time ... ;) But yea, must've more than 40, I had a second job for a while to save up a little money towards my diploma thesis. @ OP don't do that. More than 40h/month badly collide with your studies in my experience.

Comment: @Karl Very unlikely to be a problem for someone in the USA because there's no student social security. Might be a problem if OP is on a student visa or has a restrictive scholarship/fellowship.

Comment: @mkennedy I'm not aware of anything like that that would apply to me. Many students in similar situations at my university work.